# Building API and JSON: Retrieving data from multiple URLs

Tags: json, api

I am new to app development, and I am currently working on an iOS app (using Swift), part of which involves retrieving data from three different webpages. The three webpages can be accessed via three separate links on a website: 
http://blogs.cuit.columbia.edu/habitat/build/

How can I compile the data from those three webpages into a single JSON file such that the information from those webpages are in a nested format as shown below?

```
[Build Name]
     [Date]
     [Time]
     [Info]
```

So far, I have used WrapAPI to parse out data from the website into the following JSON file:

```
...{ "success": true,"outputScenario": "Default", "data": {
"BuildsSection": {
  "Builds": [
    "Build: Habitat NYC April 8th",
    "Friends of Rockaway April 15th",
    "Build: Rebuilding Together NYC April 29th"
  ]
}
```

},...

I have created a similar JSON file for the information presented for each build. How would I combine the build name and the information of the build into one JSON file?

Thank you.

Comment: Show us what you have already tried and where that failed.

Comment: Thanks! I have updated the question.